# wxWidgets wx/version.h file not found

Tags: c++, cmake, wxwidgets, msys2

I am using VS Code and I want to compile C++ code that use wxWidgets3.2 via cmake.

I installed:

- mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
- mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake
- mingw-w64-x86_64-wxwidgets3.2-msw

During cmake configure i got this following error:

```
[variant] Loaded new set of variants
[kit] Successfully loaded 2 kits from C:\Users\walkiewi\AppData\Local\CMakeTools\cmake-tools-kits.json
[proc] Executing command: C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -v
[main] Configuring folder: jcp 
[proc] Executing command: C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\cmake.EXE --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -Sc:/Users/walkiewi/Documents/projects/jcp -Bc:/Users/walkiewi/Documents/projects/jcp/build -G "MinGW Makefiles"
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] CMake Error at C:/msys64/mingw64/share/cmake/Modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake:225 (message):
[cmake]   wxWidgets wx/version.h file not found in C:/Program;C:/Program.
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   C:/msys64/mingw64/share/cmake/Modules/FindwxWidgets.cmake:955 (wx_extract_version)
[cmake]   CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
[cmake] See also "C:/Users/walkiewi/Documents/projects/jcp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
[proc] The command: C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\cmake.EXE --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -Sc:/Users/walkiewi/Documents/projects/jcp -Bc:/Users/walkiewi/Documents/projects/jcp/build -G "MinGW Makefiles" exited with code: 1 and signal: null
```

I tried changing two lines in FindwxWidgets.cmake

from

```
if(WIN32 AND NOT CYGWIN AND NOT MSYS AND AND NOT CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
if(wxWidgets_FOUND AND MSYS)
```

to:

```
if(WIN32 AND NOT CYGWIN AND NOT MSYS AND NOT MINGW AND NOT CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
if(wxWidgets_FOUND AND (MSYS OR MINGW))
```

But the error is still present

Comment: You've probably installed `wxWidgets` under `C:\Program Files\ `. Try installing it under a path that does not contain spaces.

Comment: I did not.
I only instaled wxWidgets via MSYS2
and it is located in 
C:\msys64\mingw64\include\wx-3.2

Comment: ```
error: wxWidgets wx/version.h file not found in C:/Program;C:/Program
```
suggested that it was looking in `C:\Program Files\ `. I think that was the problem, even though I don't know what caused it..

Comment: I applied a workaround.
On my other PC, I had a similar MSYS2 setup (a little bit older) and it is working there.
So I copied the whole msys64 directory.

But still, I don't know what was wrong.
Maybe some bug in the newest versions of mentioned packages.